# Replace a website's CSS with my own

Tags: css, fiddler

I was wondering whether it is possible to override a website's CSS with my own? I have seen a blog about how to replace a `.js` file from the website with Fiddler2. I'm guessing this is possible for CSS files too, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @sgmart: Sorry I'm not following. Tried what with FTP Access?

Comment: **This link might help you**

http://superuser.com/questions/52967/change-default-css-of-google-chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's trivial to do this with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com), and it's done in the exact same way as replacing a JS file. Simply drag/drop the site's stylesheet to Fiddler's AutoResponder tab, then edit the file or replace it with your own. Or write FiddlerScript to do the same thing. This will work with ANY browser.

Comment: Since this works for ANY browser as you mentioned, I'm setting this as answer. Although I think I might switch from IE10 to FF just for this reason. Maybe.

Comment: How can this be an answer? What is "Fiddler"? Can you put in a link?

Comment: @SwissMister: Paste "What is Fiddler" in Google and hit Enter.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post. When I see a 2 year old post with a mere _word_, and when googling for it not only gives many answers, but the first hit costs something, I'd rather be sure it is the tool that's meant. I'd say putting in a precise link improves stackoverflow.

Comment: Oops - I see this one product is free (albeit not OSS). And I admit it is awesome! I can't believe I have never come across it in so many years fiddling and developing web pages and apps! Thanks Eric!

Answer (score 2):

If you use Firefox, you can try this [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/).

And this [the same addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe), but this one is for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom stylesheet to any page with your browser, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I want it to be permanent. I know I can use Firebug to replace a site's css but I want the changes to be there when I refresh the page.